# Using routerLink inside angular template

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
  <a *ngIf="userBS$ | async"
    [routerLink]="{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}">
  </a>
```

User is a Behaviour subject defined line this:

```
this.userBS$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.currentUser);
```

Here is the error message:

> compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error:
>   Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in
>   [{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4 (" 
>   ][routerLink]="{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (authServic"): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or
>   string at column 2 in [{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4 (" 
>   ][routerLink]="{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (authServic"): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 58 in [{{
>   '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4 (" 
>   ][routerLink]="{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (authServic"): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 58 in [{{
>   '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4 (" 
>   ][routerLink]="{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (authServic"): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token '}' at column 59 in [{{
>   '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4 (" 
>   ][routerLink]="{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (authServic"): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
>   at column 0 in [{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4 ("
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>   [ERROR ->]
>         [ERROR ->]{{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         
>         [ERROR ->]{{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         
>         [ERROR ->]{{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         
>         [ERROR ->]{{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         
>         [ERROR ->]{{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         
>         {{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         ][src]="user_image" class="user-icon">      "): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@5:11
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or
>   string at column 2 in [{{ '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   ("sync)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         ][src]="user_image" class="user-icon">      "): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@5:11
>   Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 58 in [{{
>   '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   ("sync)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         ][src]="user_image" class="user-icon">      "): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@5:11
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 58 in [{{
>   '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   ("sync)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         ][src]="user_image" class="user-icon">      "): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@5:11
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token '}' at column 59 in [{{
>   '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid }}] in
>   ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@3:4
>   ("sync)?.uid }}">
>         {{ (userBS$ | async)?.displayName }}
>         ][src]="user_image" class="user-icon">      "): ng:///AppHeaderNavbarModule/AppHeaderNavbarUserComponent.html@5:11
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
>       at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24329)
>       at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:33716)
>       at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:33691)
>       at eval (compiler.js:33593)
>       at Set.forEach ()
>       at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:33593)
>       at eval (compiler.js:33463)
>       at Object.then (compiler.js:455)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:33462)

Comment: Can you try with this- `[routerLink]=" '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid">`

Comment: Yes it works. move it to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note it is not recommended to use `" "` & `{{ }}` syntax together in data binding in template. **eg `"{{ expression }}"`**. So just remove `{{ }}` from the template data binding as shown below,

```
[routerLink]=" '/profile/'+(userBS$ | async)?.uid">
```